# How can I achieve SQL query in GROUP_CONCAT to seperate with ',' and ends with '&'

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to achieve and SQL statement to query to GROUP_CONCAT all the classes which separates with commas if more than 2 classes and also ends with '&' for the last class and If no comma if only 1 class.

```
SELECT `tbl_perfumes`.`pk_int_perfumeID` AS `Perfume ID`,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `tbl_notes`.`txt_noteName`  ORDER BY `tbl_notes`.`txt_noteName` ASC SEPARATOR ', 
' ) AS `Notes` FROM `tbl_notes` JOIN `tbl_perfumeNotes`
ON `tbl_notes`.`pk_int_noteID` = `tbl_perfumeNotes`.`fk_int_noteID`
JOIN `tbl_perfumes` ON `tbl_perfumeNotes`.`fk_int_perfumeID` = `tbl_perfumes`.`pk_int_perfumeID`
WHERE `tbl_perfumes`.`pk_int_perfumeID`=1
GROUP BY `tbl_perfumes`.`pk_int_perfumeID`
```

```
ie; (1)
    (1 & 2)
    (1, 2, 3 & 4)
```

Comment: This is probably most easily achieved in your application layer.

Comment: For next time, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query